# extract data from row with VBA

Tags: excel, vba

i have this data [image]

I would like to extract Size and Color like this:

```
ID Color Size
1 Blue S
1 Blue M
1 Blue  L
1 Blue XL
1 Blue  XXL
```

I can have also 2 values for color separated with a comma. I would like to have the results like this:

```
ID Color Size
18 Rose S
18 Rose M
18 Rose L
18 Rose XL
18 Rose XXL
18 White S
18 White M
18 White L
18 White XL
18 White XXL
```

I have tried this in VBA:

```
Sub MG11Sep42()
Dim Rng As Range, Dn As Range, Sp As Variant, Sp1 As Variant, Sp2 As Variant, Sp3 As Variant
Dim n As Long, Col As Variant, Sz As Variant, c As Long
Set Rng = Range("B1", Range("B" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp))
Cells(1, "D").Resize(, 3) = Array("ID", "Color", "Size")
c = 1
For Each Dn In Rng
    Sp = Split(Dn.Value, ":")
    Sp1 = Split(Sp(1), ";")
    Sp2 = Split(Sp(UBound(Sp)), ",")
    Sp3 = Split(Sp1(0), ",")
        For Each Sz In Sp2
            For Each Col In Sp3
                c = c + 1
                Cells(c, "D") = Dn.Offset(, -1).Value
                Cells(c, "E") = Sz
                Cells(c, "F") = Col
            Next Col
        Next Sz
Next Dn
End Sub
```

but error is : **index out of range**

[image]

Comment: You need to skip the first row, since that has only the column labels.  Else you will get that error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you need to skip the first row.  Perhaps (not debugged):

```
For Each Dn In Rng.offset(1,0).resize(rowsize:=rng.rows.count-1)
    Sp = Split(Dn.Value, ":")
    Sp1 = Split(Sp(1), ";")
```